# ¿Como hacer un consulta con varios pipes con python sobre una base de datos MongoDB [Errno 111]?

Tags: python, mongodb

Quiero hacer una consulta sobre una base de datos mongoDB con un script python que me permitirá modificar la consulta sobre el horario. Sin embargo no estoy capaz visualizar el resultado :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pymongo
import datetime
import pprint

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://swiper_read:...')

db = MongoClient().aggregation_example

# // Pipeline
pipeline =[
         { "subscribedFlux": { "$exists": "true" } }
    ]

a = pprint.pprint(list(db.things.aggregate(pipeline)))

print a
```

Pero me dice el terminal :

```
:~$ python testMongoDB.py 
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.databases
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.uriVersion
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.connectionMode
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.connection.name
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testMongoDB.py", line 47, in <module>
    a = pprint.pprint(list(db.multifeeds.aggregate(pipeline))) # fue lo que utilisaba antes
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1845, in aggregate
    with self._socket_for_reads() as (sock_info, slave_ok):
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 859, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 823, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
    address))
  File "/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Hay una imformacion sobre donde esta pymongo :

```
$ pip install pymongo
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

No tengo `mongod.conf` `mongodb.conf` en `etc`

#### Actualizacion 24/5/2017

He instalado mongodb-server :

```
sudo apt install mongodb-server
```

Y hoy tengo un error

```
exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$count'
```

Pienso, segun [ares, que da una respuesta sobre SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670887/meteor-mongo-aggregate-does-not-have-count-stage) que no tengo la ultima version de mongodb pero me permite tambien hacer :

```
pipeline =[
        {
            "$match": {
             "subscribedFlux": { "$exists": "true" }
            }
        },


       {
        "$group": {
          "_id" : "null", 
          "count" : {"$sum" : "1"}
        }
      }
    ]
```

y obtener un resultado que no es verdad segun :

```
[]
None
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No deberian ser cadenas los comandos?, es decir: `{"$group": {"_id": "$tags", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},` o `"$count": "count"` por ejemplo.

Comment: Tal vez ... con comandos cadenadas desplace la flecha del error sobre el argumento de ISODate :

`ISODate("2017-05-17T00:00:00.000+0000")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`